# express the following statements as formulas in first-order predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate, discrete-mathematics

Let:
• B(x) for “x has bifurcated horns”
• D(x) for “x suffers from dermal asthenia”
• F(x) for “x is female”
• M(x, y) for “x is the mother of y”
• S(x) for “x is Syldavian”
• U(x) for “x is a unicorn”

How do I express 
1)  "Mother unicorns with dermal asthenia pass the condition on to all their offspring"

2)  "Any unicorn whose mother is Syldavian suffers from dermal asthenia" 
in first-order predicate logic?

My attempt
1) 
there exist a x and for all y, 
if x is mother of y 
and x is a unicorn 
and x has dermal asthenia, 
it implies y have dermal asthenia too.
∃x∀y(  (M(x,y) ∧  U(x) ∧ D(x) ) ->  D(y)  )

2) 
for all x and y,
if  y is a unicorn
and x is mother of y,
and x is Syldavian,
it implies y has dermal asthenia

∀x∀y(  (  U(y) ∧   M(x,y) ∧ S(x)   )  ->  B(y)   )

Any help would be appreciated, especially on when to use ∀ and when to use ∃.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Mother unicorns with dermal asthenia pass the condition on to all their offspring"

∀x∀y((M(x,y) ∧ U(x) ∧ D(x)) -> D(y))

"Any unicorn whose mother is Syldavian suffers from dermal asthenia"

∀x∀y((M(x,y) ∧ U(y) ∧ S(x)) -> D(x))

Here there is no statements "there exists" or "at least one". These statements are about all unicorns so we do not use ∃.